# RobinBrouwer WMD - Reading Basic jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, wmd

I'm new to jQuery (and truth be told I am only using it because [this](https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/wmd) WMD editor requires it).

Anyway, I am looking at the jQuery code (go to the above link and view jquery.wmd.js) and there are option defaults:

```
WMDEditor.defaults = { // {{{
version: 2.0,
output_format:"markdown",
lineLength:40,

button_bar: "wmd-button-bar",
preview: "wmd-preview",
output: "wmd-output",
input: "wmd-input",

...
```

Which leads me to believe that there is a way to pass on the options as arguments to the function. I am looking for a way to pass on the `helpLink` option. I am sure it is really easy, like facepalm easy, but I can't read jQuery and there is no documentation. Can someone show me how to pass on option arguments to this

```
$(function() {
     $(".wmd-input").wmd(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plugin is setup normally you can do this:

```
var defaults = { 
    version: 2.0,
    output_format:"markdown",
    lineLength:40,

    button_bar: "wmd-button-bar",
    preview: "wmd-preview",
    output: "wmd-output",
    input: "wmd-input"
    // and then keep on going
}

$(function() {
     $(".wmd-input").wmd(defaults); 
});
```

Comment: You will be passing an object so you need `{}` around your parameters like this: `$(".wmd-input").wmd({helpLink: "http://"})`.That should work if the plugin is setup corrently